# How can I link my JSON extension to the correct Ruby version?

Tags: c, ruby

If I install Ruby 2.1.6 (or 2.2.2, etc) and try to `require 'json'`, I get a segfault. I [reported this](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11112) and was told "Your json extension is linked to ruby 2.0.0, not ruby 2.1.6."

I install my Ruby versions with [`ruby-install`](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install), and I don't really understand the details of compiling Ruby.

How can get this extension to link to the right version of Ruby?

### Clarification

This is a question about compiling the C source of the Ruby executable. It requires C knowledge to answer, not just Ruby knowledge; that's why I tagged it with both languages.

**My real goal is to be able to `rails server` with the latest Ruby version (currently 2.2.2)**. Doing `require 'json'` sometimes triggers the segfault, but `rails s` always does.

### Update

I'm looking for someone to walk me through figuring out and fixing this.

I've tried moving my entire `~/.rubies` folder to `~/.old_rubies` and doing `ruby-install ruby 2.2.2` from scratch. I've tried uninstalling every JSON gem it will let me (although it won't let me remove a default gem). Sometimes `irb; require 'json'` works, but starting rails server always segfaults.

Comment: Why did you put the `C` tag?

Comment: could you post your "gem env" ?

Comment: @MohitJain Probably because Ruby (MRI) is written in C, and you can't normally get segfaults in pure Ruby code without either a bug in the C portion of Ruby, or some other bit of binary code that the C code is linked to.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Thanks. This makes sense. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @MohitJain Installing MRI Ruby involves compiling the Ruby executables from C code. "Linking" is not a thing one does in Ruby, but this particular linking is one that Ruby needs. So this question is really at the intersection of C and Ruby.

Comment: @HoracioBranciforte gem env here: https://gist.github.com/nathanl/e15a1871a9b3e434a8bb

Comment: And how are you installing the json gem?

Comment: And be aware that if you run things with "sudo" that changes the environment (eg it might reset the PATH environment variable)

Comment: @NathanLong: What is your goal -- to be able to type `require 'json'` in some version of Ruby and have it work? Or do you want it to work specifically with 2.2.2?

Comment: @JohnFeminella really my goal is to be able to `rails server` with Ruby 2.2.2.

Comment: @JohnFeminella I knew your name sounded familiar - we both spoke at GoGaRuCo 2014! You: http://confreaks.tv/videos/gogaruco2014-why-we-can-t-have-nice-things-floats-dates-and-names Me: http://confreaks.tv/videos/gogaruco2014-reimplementing-ruby-s-hash And yet here I am asking a n00b question. :D I don't have to have nice things, I just don't want scary segfaults!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Adrian OSX - 10.10.4

Comment: Are you attached to using ruby-install? Do you want to have multiple versions of ruby installed at a time?

Comment: @Adrian I could probably use one version right now, but I will likely want to switch between projects that use different ones. I use `chruby` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're dealing with a classic dependency-hell problem.

First things first: we need to isolate your environment. We don't want your OS-installed Ruby or its gems interfering with your project-installed Ruby.

Install these tools:

- install `ruby-install`: https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install
- install `chruby`: https://github.com/postmodern/chruby
- install `gem_home`: https://github.com/postmodern/gem_home

and follow the Homebrew directions for each.

Now install your preferred Ruby:

```
ruby-install ruby 2.2.2
```

Navigate to your project directory:

```
cd ~/projects/operation-snugglepants
```

Switch to your preferred Ruby:

```
chruby 2.2.2
```

Then ensure you're not being pre-empted by a system Ruby:

```
which ruby
```

should give you a path like

```
~/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby
```

and verify that it's the right version:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 ...
```

Great -- now you've got the right Ruby. Let's make sure you have the right gems. Set your gem installation target to your project's directory:

```
gem_home .
```

and install bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

then install your gems:

```
bundle install
```

After that's done, now `bundle rails server` and verify it's all working:

```
bundle exec rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
```

Always make sure you've isolated your *system* dependencies (system Ruby and system gems) from your *application* dependencies (application Ruby and application gems). Never mix the two if at all possible.

I also use a [short Bash script](https://github.com/fj/dotfiles/blob/master/home/.config/shell/additions-ruby.sh) that loads some aliases on my shell's startup to "jump" into my Ruby-project-specific environments, to make things easier to work with -- feel free to swipe it!

Comment: Thanks for this. Sadly, I still get the segfault when trying to `bundle exec rails server`. Everything looked right up until then.

Comment: Do you get the segfault if you `bundle exec irb` and `require 'json'`?

Comment: No. Right now I don't get it if I just `irb` and `require 'json'`, only when I try to start rails. I wish I knew how to read a segfault dump.

Comment: That sounds like you're getting closer, then: the thing causing the segfault isn't `json` anymore. You should be able to diff your segfault dumps and see what changed.

Comment: **Mother of pearl, it works!** `gem_home` really was the key, but I had to uninstall a bunch of gems first. I'm going to add an answer to elaborate, but yours will be the accepted one, and the bounty shall be yours. Thank you! :D

Comment: The plot thickened and I think I found the root cause - accidentally using `/usr/bin/bundle`. See update on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### What worked

[John Feminella's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31733926/4376) helped me fix it, but I wanted to elaborate a bit on what I did.

First, I uninstalled every version of the `json` gem except the default one and installed a newer version. The next time I ran `rails s`, I saw that the segfault happened when trying to require `nokogiri`. I thought, "maybe it's any gem with a C extension?"

My guess was that they all needed to be recompiled, but that `bundle install` was finding the old versions elsewhere in `$GEM_PATH` and therefore not installing / recompiling new versions in `$GEM_HOME`.

So I followed John's instructions, got to the point where I was in the project folder and had run `gem_home .`, then uninstalled every gem I could using this Ruby script:

```
`gem list --no-versions`.split("\n").each do |gem|
  `gem list -d #{gem}`.gsub(/Installed at(.*):.*/).each do |dir|
    dir = dir.gsub(/Installed at(.*): /,'').gsub("\n", '')
    system "gem uninstall #{gem} -aIx -i #{dir}"
  end  
end
```

After that, I ran `bundle install`, which, because I had done `gem_home .`, put the new versions in `my_project_folder/.gem/ruby/2.2.2`.

Then when I ran `rails s`, it didn't segfault!

In conclusion, **YAAAAAAY!!!** :D

### UPDATE: In which I think I've discovered the root cause

I think I've been able to discover the root cause. I could get segfaults again like this:

- Install a new version of Ruby (or rename the gem dir for a version, eg, `~/.gem/ruby/2.2.0` to `2.2.0_inactive`)
- `cd my_project` and `chruby 2.2.0`
- `bundle install` # => error, no such gem
- `gem install bundler` #=> worked fine
- `which bundle` # => **OH WHAT, it's `/usr/bin/bundle`**
- `bundle install` # **this will create sadness**.

Why? Since there are no gems for this Ruby yet, `which bundle` points to `/usr/bin/bundle` - the one that came with system Ruby. Any gems that `bundle install` compiles code for may cause segfaults when trying to use a different Ruby version.

If instead, before running `bundle install`, I `chruby 2.2.2`, `which bundle` gives `~/.gem/ruby/2.1.2/bin/bundle`, as it should, and `bundle install` works fine.

**Here's what I've done to prevent this in the future**: edit the Ruby script at `/usr/bin/bundle` to `puts` a warning and `exit`. Same for `/usr/bin/bundler` and `/usr/bin/rails`, for good measure.